# Spell check without auto-correct?

Tags: applications, keyboard, auto-correct, spell-check

I find more often than not auto correct makes incorrect suggestions.

Is it possible to get a spell check similar to that on desktop where it underlines mistakes in red?

Comment: What keyboard are you using? Google Keyboard? If not, please also specify the device model and Android version.

Comment: Cm13 standard android keyboard